# Check if two vars are set?

Tags: php

Depending on whether 2 vars are set ($skip and $take) I want to do different things. I have a large if else statement, is there a more efficient way to write this?

```
    if (isset($skip) && !isset($take)) {
        //skip only
    } elseif (!isset($skip) && isset($take)) {
        //take only
    } elseif (isset($skip) && isset($take)) {
        //skip and take
    } else {
        //default
    }
```

---

Edit

It should also be noted that this is to sit in a method where the vars will be set to null if not specified:

```
getAll($skip = null, $take = null)
```

Comment: I don't think so you have 4 cases you need 4 blocks, you may choose `if (isset($a) ) { if (isset($b) { } else {} } else { if (isset($b) { } else {} }` depends which you find more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP clarified in a comment that this is inside a method, and both `$skip` and `$take` are arguments with default values, one might favor  `===` over `isset`. Furthermore, you can re-arrange the logic a bit:

```
function getAll($skip = null, $take = null) {

    if ($skip !== null && $take !== null) {
        // both
    } elseif ($skip !== null) {
        // skip only
    } elseif ($take !== null) {
        // take only
    } else {
        // none
    }
}
```

The `===` operator enforces an equality check with type safety.

The way default values for arguments work, the arguments are *always* guaranteed to be `null` if you don't pass them, so the equality check is a good way to check them here.

Comment: What if you don't need to know if they have put any value in the field? Surely if it is flag-like there is no need for that. For example, a query string which contains `?take` would be enough to suggest that you want to perform the take action instead of writing `?take=true`

Comment: @Henders True. But not using `empty` is a common pitfall for novices. So I think its appropriate to mention it, so that the Op can figure out wether its appropriate to use here.

Comment: My method has getAll($skip = null, $take = null)

Comment: @panthro In that case, `isset` is wrong alltogether, and you should use `$skip === null` (note the *three* equal signs), since both `$skip` and `$take` will *always* be set. Please update the question to include this information.

Answer (score 9):

You can simplify the logic a bit:

```
if (isset($skip) && isset($take)) {
    // skip and take
} elseif (isset($skip)) {
    // only skip
} elseif (isset($take)) {
    // only take
} else {
    // default 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you dont like if else

```
$switch = (int)isset($skip) + (int)isset($take)*2;
switch($switch){
    case 0:
    //default
    break;
    case 1:
    //only skip
    break;
    case 2:
    //only take
    break;
    case 3:
    //skip and take
    break;
}
```

Comment: While this might be "clever", its horrible for production code. Don't do this. Write straight-forward, easy to understand code. Things like these, who are just unnecessary are annoying for everyone else to read through. Furthermore, it doesn't address the updated question correctly.

Comment: you re right! just found a different way from the if else method.... result is a not so readable solution